# How to read a ".txt" file containing depth values and then convert it into an image using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, kinect, gesture-recognition, image-thresholding

I want to do depth thresholding and other processing on the depth text files provided in the NTU-Microsoft-Kinect-HandGesture Dataset. It is not possible for me to attach the text file in this question. Thus, it's link is given as:

http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~zhou.ren/

The dataset is under the paper "Robust Hand Gesture Recognition based on Finger-Earth Mover’s Distance with a Commodity Depth Camera" in the above link.

I know how to open, read and then process the .bin file containing depth values but I am not able to do the same for the text files in the given dataset.

Comment: may I ask what stops you from entering "matlab read text file" into google?

Comment: I did but not much as I had other tasks lined up so asked here for fast answer. Well, now I have found out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%% Initialize variables.
filename = 'D:\dsktop\NTU-MSR-Kinect-HandGesture-Dataset\Depth\P1\G1\1.txt';
delimiter = ',';
formatSpec ='%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 
'string', 'EmptyValue', NaN,  'ReturnOnError', false);
fclose(fileID);
Untitled = [dataArray{1:end-1}]; 
%Instead of numeric array, there are many other options like table, 
character array etc.
clearvars filename delimiter formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;
```

Comment: Use text PGM image format. Matlab opens them smoothly.